# How to remove PATH variable on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line

I've `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen"` in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` after export then `lumen` command not working, 
`Rasel Khan:~$ lumen`
`lumen: command not found`
But if command type `~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen` in terminal then working, i want only when `lumen` command type in terminal then exactly same as screenshot.
 how can i fix this ?

see screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your problem will not be solved simply by unsetting PATH, as you'll still be left without a PATH that includes the necessary system directories.  When you set your own PATH, in most cases you will want to append your new entry to the old PATH variable, not replace it entirely, as you have done.

Set your PATH variable back to the system default by typing

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

and then go edit your .bashrc and .bash_profile to have the correct entry, which will be something like

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Notice the variable is set to begin with the existing $PATH.  This way, you'll still have all the original system directories in your PATH, and your addition will be on the end.  Also note that I *removed* lumen from the end of your example, because lumen is apparently the name of the binary you are trying to execute, and your PATH should include only *directories* containing binaries, not the binaries themselves.

Comment: thanks, i've now default system, but i want to working this comman d`export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen` , how can i fix this so when command type `lumen` in terminal and with working

Comment: still not working others command, i want reset default

Comment: any command not working  like `ls`........etc, i want to remove only this path `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen" `  in ` .bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

Comment: See my edited remarks above.  I hadn't noticed earlier that lumen was the name of your binary, not the name of the directory containing your binaries.

Comment: still `lumen` command not working, see install lumen http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/installation

Comment: My suggestions above agree with the linked instructions.  You need to examine your PATH ('echo $PATH' to see it) and figure out what's amiss.

Comment: still `lumen` command not found

Comment: see my screenshot and update in original post

Comment: i've alias setup then working as well `Rasel Khan:~alias lumen="~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen" `

Answer (score 2):

Exec this to get your system default:

```
grep _PATH /etc/login.defs
```

Answer (score 1):

> The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the
>   PATH environment variable.

This error means you overwrite your default path with the added PATH vairable above.

#### How to restore the old PATH?

The default PATH variable is defined in /etc/environment.

To restore the default PATH first delete the add line `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen"` from your `.bashrc`

Then save and source using command:

```
source .bashrc
```

then delete from `.bash_profile` then save and source:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Now source /etc/environment to restore the default path

```
source /etc/environment
```

Now your default PATH is restored, you can check by running `echo $PATH`

#### Adding new path to PATH variable

Now to add a new PATH use:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/
```

EDIT: The error here raises because we add the binary itself so check the above line

Add the line to `.bashrc` then save and source:

```
source .bashrc
```

Check running `$PATH` you should see your new added path.

Comment: not working this command

Comment: Check the update

Comment: after adding in `.bashrc` file Rasel Khan:~$ lumen
lumen: command not found, `Rasel Khan:~$ echo $PATH`
`/home/khan/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/khan/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen`

Comment: `lumen` is the binary?

Comment: Check the edit please

Comment: check my edit or update comment above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24902/discussion-between-rasel-khan-and-maythux).

Comment: see my screenshot and update in original post

Comment: All you have is to `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin/`

Answer (score 1):

the PATH stores all the places where the terminal looks for your applications/scripts etc... If you set the PATH to some "unfriendly" directory, the system will not be able to find /bin/sudo and others. You will have to type the whole path like /bin/sudo. The best way to fix this is to open your bash_profile and insert this line: export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games I think changing the profile will work just after the next reboot, so do this and after that use the command `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` to fix it for the current session.

"Protip :D :D"
if you want to check for your own programs in a directory "/home/username/foo/bin", just add this way to your PATH and you will be able to call the programs stored there just by their names

Hope it helps :)

Comment: And for your question above, to unset a variable use `unset PATH` but this will **NOT** help you in this case

Comment: see my screenshot and update in original post

Comment: i've alias setup then working as well Rasel Khan:~alias lumen="~/.composer/vendor/bin/lumen"

Comment: You need to set your PATH back to what I've told you, AND ADD your path. so it should look like export PATH="/usr/<all in post above>:Lumenpath". And also, Lumenpath isn't the path to the executable lumen, but to the directory where you expect to find lumen