# '/bin' is not included in the PATH variable after installing Java JDK 8.1

Tags: environment-variables, paths

I installed Java JDK 8.1. Now I have this issue.

```
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$  ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

---

```
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /bin/cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /bin/cat ~/.pam_environment
/bin/cat: /home/mohammed/.pam_environment: No such file or directory
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /bin/cat ~/.bash_profile
/bin/cat: /home/mohammed/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /bin/cat ~/.bash_login
/bin/cat: /home/mohammed/.bash_login: No such file or directory
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.profile ~/.profile
mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
117a118,121
> 
> #JAVA HOME directory setup
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121
> export PATH="SPATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

This happens even with `sudo` `enter code here`

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when you can copy and paste. Instead, copy the text, paste it into your question, select it with your mouse, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove PATH variable on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637017/how-to-remove-path-variable-on-ubuntu-14-04) Read Maythux's answer.

Comment: mohammed@mohammed-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ /usr/bin/diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
117a118,121
> 
> #JAVA HOME directory setup
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_121
> export PATH="SPATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
@EliahKagan

Comment: can you understand it NOW @EliahKagan

Comment: You have a typo of S (cap s) instead of $ (dollar) in your last export PATH, so you lost the original values in $PATH.

Comment: Mohammed_Alkutrani: Yes, thanks for the edit. [ubfan1 has identified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877810/bin-is-not-included-in-the-path-variable-after-installing-java-jdk-8-1?noredirect=1#comment1366034_877810) the cause of the problem: the line `export PATH="SPATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"` in `~/.bashrc` should be `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"` instead. @ubfan1 I'm voting to reopen this so you can post an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem is the typo in your `.bashrc` file, where a capital s is used in place of a dollar sign for the `export PATH`.  It should look like:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

instead of

```
export PATH="SPATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Now `.bashrc` is for non-login shells -- I typically use `.profile` to change my PATH variable.  If you manually picked the `.bashrc` to make the change, I'd suggest  making the `JAVA_HOME` modifications at the end of your `.profile`, but if the install selected `.bashrc`, then leave it, unless things don't work.